# Disable html validation and cleanup in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

We have additional placeholders, which are embeded in conent edited by CKEditor and we need to be possible to place such placeholders before and after TR-tag, so we could organize repeating of data in the table. But CKEditor probably find that is not valid HTML and take out repeater placeholders before the table.
For example I write next html in source mode:

```
<table><tbody>{start}<tr><td>...</td></tr>{end}</tbody></table>
```

I switch to html mode and back to source, now my html is treated to the next view:

```
<p>{start}{end}</p> <table><tbody><tr><td>...</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Possibly there is a CKEditor switch to turn off all syntax cleanup or specially for tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CKEditor is not a source code editor, but a WYSIWYG editor which uses browsers' `contenteditable` implementations for its editing feature. Therefore, it needs to work on **valid and real HTML**.

Although, check the [config.protectedSource](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-protectedSource) setting. You'll be able to hide those `{start|end}` tags from parser.

Answer (score 7):

Try Adding this line to Config.js file:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```